# Swing Application Framework session store

Tags: java, swing, saf

I have been using the Swing Application Framework, and very pleased with its sessions state storage.
I was wondering if it's possible to delete (clean up) the persisted states.

- of All dialog forms.
  or
- of specific dialog forms.

If not, has anyone found a clean way to achieve this (stored files aren't saved in the same location depending on the OS etc..).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can delete the corresponding file/s (forgot the exact details about the naming) via the LocalStorage, here's a code snippet I use (with bsaf, but didn't change much, afair)

```
/**
 * Deletes the session state by deleting the file. Useful during development
 * when restoring to old state is not always the desired behaviour.
 * Pending: this is incomplete, deletes the mainframe state only.
 */
protected void deleteSessionState() {
    ApplicationContext context = getContext();
    try {
        context.getLocalStorage().deleteFile("mainFrame.session.xml");
    } catch (...) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed. I will use a variant of what you coded, to delete them ALL.

Answer (score 0):

```
        File directory = context.getLocalStorage().getDirectory();
        directory = directory.getCanonicalFile();
        Files.deleteDirectoryContents(directory);
```

`Files` is the google io lib.

Comment: this does NOT work if the application is launched using Java Web Start.